# Cannot generate model in Yii framework using Gii, warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

Whenever I try to generate a model using Gii in the Yii framework, it throws:

> php warning : count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

It also mentions following file:

> app\protected\vendor\yiisoft\yii\framework\gii\generators\model\ModelCode.php(371)

While questions with same title exists, none of them fixed mine.I'm using yii version 1.1.14 and windows 10

Comment: pls expand your problem description with version  of yii, php are you using and OS

Comment: done. I'm using yii version 1.1.14 and windows 10

Answer (score 3):

You should upgrade Yii to 1.1.21 - this bug [was fixed](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/commit/9e5e427c13af7c67bb5d4ca77516a32b7c7a98b0) almost 2 years ago.

Comment: I have to use Yii 1.1.14 as I need to contribute a existing project written with version 1.1.14

Comment: `1.1.21` is patch release for `1.1.14`, it should be relatively safe to upgrade (see https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/UPGRADE for details). Yii 1.1.14 is 6 years old, it has know security issues and it is incompatible with last PHP version - you **should** upgrade anyway, using this version on production is unsafe.

Comment: Also you can downgrade your PHP to 7.1 or older (not recommended)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to fix it without upgrading your existing Yii version, then follow as below.
Go to

> framework/gii/generators/model/ModelCode.php:371

and fix with

```
$pk=$table->primaryKey;
$count=is_array($pk) ? count($pk) : 1;
return ($count === 2 // we want 2 columns
```

Just check the $pk is an array or not and store value in a new variable $count and return it.

Answer (score -2):

Downgrading Php to 5.6 works fine with the older versions of yii.

Comment: Please don't suggest this. This version is not supported anymore.

Comment: Yes , it will solve the problem while its not recommended to downgrade the things